# Error: Cask 'dockertoolbox' definition is invalid: Bad header line: '{:v1_1=>"dockertoolbox"}' does not match file name

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line, homebrew

Error message:

```
$ brew cask list
Error: Cask 'dockertoolbox' definition is invalid: Bad header line: '{:v1_1=>"dockertoolbox"}' does not match file name
```

What I did , but didn't solve problem. Also info about the Homebrew installation.

```
$ brew cask uninstall dockertoolbox
Error: Cask 'dockertoolbox' definition is invalid: Bad header line: '{:v1_1=>"dockertoolbox"}' does not match file name

$ brew cask uninstall dockertoolbox --force
Error: Cask 'dockertoolbox' definition is invalid: Bad header line: '{:v1_1=>"dockertoolbox"}' does not match file name

$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  ruby

$ brew cask cleanup
==> Removing cached downloads
Nothing to do

$ brew uninstall --force brew-cask; brew update
Already up-to-date.

$ brew tap --repair  

$ brew cask doctor
==> Homebrew-Cask Version
Homebrew-Cask 1.1.13
caskroom/homebrew-cask (git revision 9f94aa; last commit 2017-04-27)
==> Homebrew-Cask Install Location
<NONE>
==> Homebrew-Cask Staging Location
/usr/local/Caskroom
==> Homebrew-Cask Cached Downloads
~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask
==> Homebrew-Cask Taps:
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask (3648 casks)
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/cloudfoundry/homebrew-tap (0 casks)
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-apache (0 casks)
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core (0 casks)
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-python (0 casks)
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-science (0 casks)
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services (0 casks)
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/zzamboni/homebrew-swisscom (5 casks)
==> Contents of $LOAD_PATH
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin16
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/universal-darwin16
/Library/Ruby/Site
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin16
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin16
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin16
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin16
==> Environment Variables
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/cmd:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/scm"
SHELL="/bin/bash"
```

`dockertoolbox` was renamed to `docker-toolbox`. See this commit:

```
git show 1cfbf12dd8233f6e5720eba271e9aa8ff440a7c7
commit 1cfbf12dd8233f6e5720eba271e9aa8ff440a7c7
Author: Joshua McKinney <joshka@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Fri Jul 29 02:48:27 2016 -0500

    Update docker-toolbox cask to v1.12.0 (#23251)

diff --git a/Casks/dockertoolbox.rb b/Casks/docker-toolbox.rb
similarity index 77%
rename from Casks/dockertoolbox.rb
rename to Casks/docker-toolbox.rb
index 82062b734..d245a6f59 100644
--- a/Casks/dockertoolbox.rb
+++ b/Casks/docker-toolbox.rb
@@ -1,17 +1,15 @@
-cask 'dockertoolbox' do
-  version '1.11.2'
-  sha256 'c5635b4ee6b5db33f543e5b10fb576f417ee8354f7c30ca769163bc64fe9bbd6'
+cask 'docker-toolbox' do
+  version '1.12.0'
+  sha256 'b06cfd858b805dd5e2bfd88cf780953ba6f326d69c4e689ad69c6d49e6cc694f'

   # github.com/docker/toolbox was verified as official when first introduced to the cask
   url "https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/download/v#{version}/DockerToolbox-#{version}.pkg"
   appcast 'https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases.atom',
-          checkpoint: 'd1f05896b28c4c17ba081e09a3801c2811acbe193a98f951342835994111d7ee'
+          checkpoint: '8f110f6dffb3a494ec8b037bbab4c761c56879a2364c6b52cd1c8ffdd8551b72'
   name 'Docker Toolbox'
   homepage 'https://www.docker.com/toolbox'
   license :apache

-  depends_on cask: 'virtualbox'
-
   pkg "DockerToolbox-#{version}.pkg"

   postflight do
```

Comment: What is "dockertoolbox"? Is this a cask you've created yourself? `brew cask install docker-toolbox` seems to work out for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Root cause was the rename from `dockertoolbox` to `docker-toolbox`. To fix it:

```
cd /usr/local/Caskroom
mv dockertoolbox docker-toolbox
```